# Denying access to all files except index.html apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Could someone help me with apache .htaccess file to deny access to all files and sub directories except for index.html on the documentroot for an apache server?

I tried:

```
<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    <Files index.html>
        Order allow,deny
    </Files>
</Location>
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch index\.html>
        Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your help, works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

On Apache 2.4.18, inside an `.htaccess` file, I found that neither `<Files index.html>` nor `<FilesMatch index\.html>` nor `<Files "">` etc. reacted to directory-index request URLs ending in a slash; they applied only if the request URL actually ended in `index.html`. I eventually managed to grant access without authentication to all URLs ending in a `/`, but require authentication for all other files, with

```
Require expr "%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '*/'"
Require valid-user
```