# Denying access to all files except index.html and some technical assets

Tags: apache-2.2

I have read [this similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/407682/denying-access-to-all-files-except-index-html-apache), but sadly it doesn't quite solve my problem. The public facing part of my static page has the following folder structure:

```
/srv/htdocs/sub.domain.com/
├── 403.html
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│   └── style.css
├── fonts
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   └── jquery.min.js
└── robots.txt
```

There are many more folders, but these are the contents I wan't to have publicly available. My idea was to allow unconditional access to the `css`, `fonts` and `js` folders and allow the individual `index.html`, `403.html` and `robots.txt` files.

```
<Directory "/srv/htdocs/sub.domain.com">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    <FilesMatch "(403|index)\.html">
         Allow from all
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "robots\.txt">
         Allow from all
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "/$">
         Allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "/(css|js|fonts)" >
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</DirectoryMatch>
```

I attempted to allow the root with my "empty file" rule `"/$"` but that doesn't work. If I only use the rule `""` or `"$"` Apache grants access to all files.

When surfing to `http://sub.domain.com/` receive a `403 Forbidden` message instead of the `index.html` contents. What rule am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can use mod_rewrite for this instead of what you have:

```
RewriteEngine on
#if matching any of the approved URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|js|fonts).* [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(403|index)\.html$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots.txt$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ 
#allow the request to pass through
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#otherwise, if the person's IP doesn't match (replace the 123 IP with the IP you want to permit)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
#send 403 forbidden (i.e. the [F] flag)
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: I was trying to follow the advice stated in the apache documentation, that I shouldn't attempt to do filtering on a per URL base, but on a filesystem base instead. But I will keep your answer in mind in case nothing else shows up the next days.