# Denying access to all files except index.php but allow access through "/" in htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

When I try limiting file access to just `index.php` using something similar to the answer in the link below I am unable to access through the directory index such as "DIRECTORY/" and "DIRECTORY".

I want to be able to do the below and deny all files except `index.php` from a `.htaccess` file in DIRECTORY.

[Denying access to all files except index.html apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/407682/denying-access-to-all-files-except-index-html-apache)

```
DIRECTORY/index.php?get1=val1  
DIRECTORY/?get1=val1  
DIRECTORY?get1=val1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow mod_dir to make the internal subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex` when requesting the bare directory, you just need to make the file match optional, so it also matches an essentially empty filename.

For example:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch ^(index\.php)?$>
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This then allows both

- `DIRECTORY/index.php?get1=val1`
- and `DIRECTORY/?get1=val1`

Where `DIRECTORY` is any directory (including the document root).

However, this does not permit `DIRECTORY?get1=val1` (no slash after the directory name). Strictly speaking, this is an invalid URL on Apache. Ordinarily, mod_dir "fixes" the URL by issuing a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash. ie. `DIRECTORY?get1=val1` is externally redirected to `DIRECTORY/?get1=val1`. Unfortunately, the authorisation directives above block mod_dir from making this redirect.

---

If you specifically wanted to allow `DIRECTORY?get1=val1` (no trailing slash) as well then you could instead do *everything* with mod_rewrite instead of mod_authz_host (Apache 2.2). For example, replace the above with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^DIRECTORY/(?!index\.php|$) - [F]
```

This blocks access to the contents of the *specific* `DIRECTORY`, but allows `/DIRECTORY/index.php` and `/DIRECTORY/` to be accessed. This doesn't do anything special with a request for `/DIRECTORY` (no trailing slash), but executes sufficiently late in the request for mod_dir to step in first and issue the 301 redirect (mentioned above).

`(?!index\.php|$)` is a *negative lookahead* - which is successful when `index.php` or `$` (end of URL) does *not* match. ie. It matches everything except `index.php` and *nothing*.

---

Reference:

- Allowing the directory to be accessible: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106960/htaccess-filesmatch-directorymatch-allow-jpg-html-and-directories

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.
If /?=... works easily, I think that is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the link you gave doesn't work, can you do something along the lines of

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^DIRECTORY /DIRECTORY/index.php?get1=val1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: This would result in a _redirect loop_. (Although I assumed from the OP's example that _any_ query string should be accessible, not literally just `get1=val1` - although granted, that is not explicitly stated.)

Comment: @MrWhite Of course you're right. Your answer takes care of the loop.